# Is complimentative a word?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Is 'complimentative' a word? There are a bunch of definitions online but I couldn't find it in the [British National Corpus](http://bnc.bl.uk/saraWeb.php?qy=complimentative&mysubmit=Go) or the [OED (from searching oxforddictionaries.com)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/spellcheck/all/?q=complimentative).

Does this mean I should avoid it in academia/formal writing?

Comment: You don't access the OED from that link. Try other dictionaries (eg Webster's 1913 at thefreedictionary). The word is doubtless _rarely_ used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

People would no doubt understand it, but *complimentative* is not normally used. If you are looking for a common word with the same meaning, use **complimentary**.

Comment: OED (found at oed.com) has a rather bald entry, **= complimentary**, with a solitary citation from 1778.

Comment: I always associated complimentary with something free / some sort of extra benefit. I don't know how I've never realized complimentary has been the correct word for what I've been looking for! Thanks.